# S Video performance using ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run on U 12.4

Tags: 12.04, xorg, video, radeon

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 12.4 using the `ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run` driver for my Radeon 9600.  Graphics in `Details` shows `Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV350`.  When S Video is connected an `Unknown` monitor is detected and the video output is unusable.  I have tried a dozen ways to set an `xorg.config` file for this so that I can set the output of the card to NTSC for the s video but have been unable to get an xorg.config to configure.

Believe me I have tried many of the posts and commands to get this file made and I am not even sure that setting the s video output will help.
I am VERY new to Ubuntu but have gotten everything I needed working fixed, due to posts on `AskUbuntu`.
Is there any help for this?  Id' sure like the s video working as well as it used to on XP.

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple but easily missed.  For the s-video output on this card to be configured correctly on Ubuntu, **the output MUST be connected to the TV BEFORE bootup**.  If you are already running, shut down, connect the cable to the TV and reboot.  Voila! After a few seconds of various screen attempts, Ubuntu selects the correct configuration for the S-Video output and your computer monitor.

Found this out through experimentation and more web searches.